# My Datatables Toggle Buttons won't get enabled when I am querying mysql, only the first gets enabled

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have gotten a lot of help from Stackoverflow (Many Thanks).
The issue I am having here is that I have to click on all toggle buttons on the datatable to finally get the first Switch button on the first Row (Status) to get enabled not the rest on the (Status)Column, I have gotten it to work when I am not looping through with PHP...
See screenshot and Code here:

```
            $(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function(e) 
            {
            let Disabled = $(".required").length;
            $(".required").each(function() 
            {
            if (this.checked) Disabled--;
            });

            if (Disabled) 
            {
            $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", true);
            $(".toggle-disabled")[0].bootstrapToggle('disable');
            } 
            else 
            {
            $(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", false);
            $(".toggle-disabled")[0].bootstrapToggle('enable');
            }
            });

            <table id="MyTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped table-bordered border-primary table-sm align-middle" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>                                    
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>  
            <th>Gmail</th>
            <th>Pika</th>
            <th style="text-align: center">Status</th>  
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>Brahim </td>
            <td>Ameskroud</td>
            <td>                                    
            <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" 
            data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
            <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" 
            data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
            <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>                                 
            </td>                       
            <!-- Toggle button -->                          
            <td style="text-align: center" >                                    
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="toggle-disabled"  data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success"
            data-offstyle="warning" onchange="updateStatus(17)" checked disabled>
            </td>
            <tr>
            <td>Bel Air</td>
            <td>John Baptist</td>
            <td>                                    
            <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" 
            data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
            <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" 
            data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
            <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>                                 
            </td>                       
            <!-- Toggle button -->                          
            <td style="text-align: center" >                                    
            <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="toggle-disabled"  data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success"
            data-offstyle="warning" onchange="updateStatus(50)"  disabled>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You don't need the loop. `let Disabled = $(".required:not(:checked))").length;`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `$(".toggle-disabled")["0"]` is just the first toggle button, that's what `[0]` does (why did you put it in quotes?).

Comment: @Barmar
I need a loop to get these Yes and No from the Mysql table ! and I tried your suggestion "let Disabled = $(".required:not(:checked))").length;"
Not working, 
["0"] works fine with or without Quotes but it is only Enabling the very First element on "Status" Column after ticking all available Toggle Boxes.

Comment: I was talking about this loop: `$(".required").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) Disabled--;
  });`

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. Is the problem in the JavaScript or the PHP?

Comment: "I have to click on all toggle buttons on the datatable" -- that's what the `Disabled` variable checks. `if (Disabled)` will be true if any of the checkboxes is unchecked. So you have to check all the boxes to change that.

Comment: @Barmar: what I need is in each row when I click/switch/Tick yes/no the Element (Done/Pending) in the Status Column to be enabled for that same row...

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find(".toggle-disabled").prop("enabled", true/false)`

Comment: That will find the toggle in the same row.

Comment: Ok, which part of my JS can I add this to ? a bit confused here, not that good at JS . Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).closest('tr')` to get the row that the event target is in. Then you can find the checkboxes and toggle button in the same row.

```js
$(document).on("change keyup", ".required", function() {
  let row = $(this).closest("tr");
  let disabled = row.find(".required:not(:checked)").length > 0;
  row.find(".toggle-disabled").prop("disabled", disabled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped table-bordered border-primary table-sm align-middle" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Gmail</th>
      <th>Pika</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Brahim </td>
      <td>Ameskroud</td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
        <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
        <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
      </td>
      <!-- Toggle button -->
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="toggle-disabled" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" checked disabled>
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>Bel Air</td>
        <td>John Baptist</td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="form-check-input filled-in box required" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs" data-onlabel="Yes" data-offlabel="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="info">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </td>
        <!-- Toggle button -->
        <td style="text-align: center">
          <input type="checkbox" name="status" class="toggle-disabled" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-onlabel="Done" data-offlabel="Pending" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="warning" disabled>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately now, even the first button on Status that worked earlier is not getting enabled ! something is not right in my JS !

Comment: Can you post sample HTML rather than the PHP that generates it, so I can test my code?

Comment: Code Updated to include some Data.

Comment: Why did you remove your JavaScript? How will anyone know what problem I'm fixing in the original code?

Comment: My bad I must of overwtitten it.. I restored it back.. Thank you .!

Comment: I've made an executable snippet in my answer, and it seems to work. When you check both Gmail and Pika boxes, the Status box is enabled in that row.

Comment: Yes but the second Row doesn't work ...

Comment: It works for both rows when I try it. When I check both the boxes in that row, the `Status` checkbox is enabled. Then you can click on the Status box to check or uncheck it.

Comment: Let's make sure I understand what you want: "enabled" means the user can click on the checkbox, it doesn't mean that the box is checked.

Comment: To understand more the Toggle Button on the Status (tr) is "Pending (Oragne)" and Disabled by default, I want to toggle it to "Done(Green)" when Gmail and Pika  Accounts are Created  => Ticked/Checked and only when both are Checked that the Done/Pending Button are Enabled to Toggle. Same in all rows..

Comment: I left out the Bootstrap stuff in my snippet, so it doesn't change color or label. But the logic should be the same.

Comment: It doesn't work still, as I mentioned earlier the second checkbox in Status doesn't check at all and it is broken when you use Bootstrao Toggle...

Comment: It checks for me. I don't know bootstrap well enough to answer that part, sorry.

Comment: See https://snipboard.io/yBYbDo.jpg

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I was hoping someone else would help..
I need it to work with Bootstrap. Thank you again.

Comment: As I said above, the basic logic should be the same. I can't think of any reason why adding bootstrap would affect that, unless you're calling the wrong bootstrap method.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar
It worked but not with the Bootstrap I was trying to use... especially on the Status th.